# Python 3 change the names dynamically

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, dynamic, names

```
import numpy as np
Method_name = "method_a"
#Method_name = "method_b"

def method_a (x, y):
    result = x + y
    return result

def method_b (x, y):
    result = x * y
    return result

result_method_a = np.zeros((0,1))
result_method_b = np.zeros((0,1))

x1 = 1
x2 = 5

for i in range (10):

    result = method_a(x1, x2)
    result +=1
    print (result)
    result_method_a = np.vstack((result_method_a, result))

    x1 += 1
    x2 += 5
```

Is there any way to change the names dynamically if I active method_a or method_b

for example:
if I Uncommenting the line:

```
Method_name = "method_b"
```

then I will get:

```
result = method_b(x1, x2)
```

and:

```
result_method_b = np.vstack((result_method_b, result))
```

and so on

This is a just small example.

Answer (score 2):

You could use built-in `eval()` function.

```
Method_name_a = "method_a"
Method_name_b = "method_b"

method_to_run = Method_name_a # change this as needed

def method_a (x, y):
    result = x + y
    return result

def method_b (x, y):
    result = x * y
    return result

x1 = 1
x2 = 5

res = eval(method_to_run)(x1, x2)
print(res)
```

You can recreate the same while using the numpy functions.

But, I recommend not using `eval()` especially when you're passing the user input as parameters. You can read more about it online.

#### Another solution

```
Method_name_a = "method_a"
Method_name_b = "method_b"

def method_a (x, y):
    result = x + y
    return result

def method_b (x, y):
    result = x * y
    return result

method_mapping = {
    Method_name_a: method_a,
    Method_name_b: method_b
}

method_to_run = Method_name_a

# You could also set a default function to run in case
# the desired function is not available
method = method_mapping.get(method_to_run) 

x, y = 3, 5
res = method(x, y)
print(res)
```

This solution is safe and I'd prefer it over the one which uses `eval()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Don't focus on the names, but rather the function objects.

```
if True:
    method = method_a
else:
    method = method_b

result = method((x1,x2)
```

can run either function depending on the if statement.

Functions are 'first-class' objects in Python, which can be assigned, put into lists, etc, just like numbers.

The easiest way of connecting a string with a function is with a dictionary:

```
dd = {'foo_a':method_a, 'foo_b':method_a, 'bar_a': method_b}
```

On a different matter, it is better to build a list of arrays and apply `vstack` just once:

```
alist = []
for i in range...:
   alist.append(anarray)
arr = np.vstack(alist)
```